# Slowness with creating a String from a ObjectNode with Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, performance, jackson

I have problem with creating a `String` from a `JSON` node.

Currently I'm doing it by `node.toString()` method. But in sometimes this takes 7-8 seconds to create the JSON string weighted 15MB-18MB.

I tried with `mapper.writeValueAsString(node))` method too. But it shows some additional time for the test. This is very difficult to check the issue because it is also harder to reproduce.

I'm currently using only `ObjectNode` (not `TextNode`, `BooleanNode` etc) is it this will be effect to this? Or is there any better way to convert `JSONNode` to `String` ?

**Sample Code :** 
    JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory =  JsonNodeFactory.instance;

```
ObjectNode  node  = nodeFactory.objectNode();
node.put("fnm", "Namal");
node.put("lnm", "Fernando");
node.put("age", 30);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    ObjectNode  order  = nodeFactory.objectNode();
    order.put("id", (i+1000)+"");
    order.put("nm", "ORD"+(i+1000));
    order.put("ref", "RF-"+i);

    node.put("order"+i, order);

}

long smili  = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("main().Node : " + node.toString());
System.out.println("main().TIMING 1 : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - smili) / 1000.0);;

long smili2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println("main().Node : " + mapper.writeValueAsString(node));
System.out.println("main().TIMING 2 : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - smili2) / 1000.0);;
```

Comment: If you just measure one or two elements, you won't get a relevant result. You should try with at least some hundred or thousand calls to minimize the effects of class loading, initialization etc.

Comment: There are a lot of details in micro benchmarking. Use [special tool](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for that.

Comment: @Uwe : Here I have format it. And I basically need to know this node.toString() is a better way for this or not

Comment: @Zernike : Thank you for the suggestion. I'll check that. I basically need to know this node.toString() is a better way for this or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: `JsonNode.toString()` should NOT be used for serialization, ever. It is useful for simple troubleshooting, but since it does not have access to contextual configuration, it will not necessarily produce valid JSON. This is by design.
Instead, you should use `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectWriter` to serialize it; this will produce valid JSON using exact configuration and settings that mapper has (or writer created by mapper).

Now: your timing comparison is flawed since you only do one call with `ObjectMapper`. There is overhead in first N calls; partly due to `ObjectMapper` initialization, partly due to JVM warmup (dynamic JIT compiler running to optimize and such). To get more usable results you would need to call method multiple times, and ideally let it run for couple of seconds.

But beyond this a common problem is to forget to have enough heap space.
In Java, Strings require memory at least equivalent to 2x length of String in characters (each `char` takes 2 bytes). But this is just the size of the result; during serialization a temporary buffer is also needed, using roughly comparable amount.
On disk, however, UTF-8 encoding typically uses just 1 byte per character (for ASCII characters).

So assuming you see a 15mB file, it could use 60 mB of memory during processing. If your heap size is set to small (say, 64 megs which is default in many cases) it would lead to very heavy garbage-collection processing. Solution there would be to either increase heap size.
Or, unless you actually need the String, to:

1. Write directly into file: use of intermediate `String` is an anti-pattern if the result goes into `File` or network connection
2. If you do require intermediate form, serialize as `byte[]`: this will only need same amount of memory as a file would (since it is UTF-8 encoded in memory, instead of being a wrapped `char[]`

Comment: Thank you StaxMan. This is very informative and very helpful. I changed it to objectMapper.writeValue(wr, availabilityNode); Now need to test in Production after bench marking. Thanks again.