# Deep Copy using Jackson: String or JsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson, clone

Objective: deep copy (or clone) of a Java object
One of the suggested ways (almost everywhere) to do it is using Jackson:

```java
MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo newPojo = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo), MyPojo.class);
```

Question: is the following better? in terms of performance? is there any drawbacks?

```java
MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo newPojo = mapper.treeToValue(mapper.valueToTree(myPojo), MyPojo.class);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Answered by Tatu Saloranta:

> Second way should be bit more efficient since it only creates and uses
>   logical token stream but does not have to encode JSON and then decode (parse) it to/from token stream. So that is close to optimal regarding
>   Jackson.
>
> About the only thing to make it even more optimal would be to directly
>   use `TokenBuffer` (which is what Jackson itself uses for buffering). Something like:
>
> ```
> TokenBuffer tb = new TokenBuffer(); // or one of factory methods
> mapper.writeValue(tb, myPojo);
> MyPojo copy = mapper.readValue(tb.asParser(), MyPojo.class);
> ```
>
> This would further eliminate construction and traversal of the tree model. I don't know how big a difference it'll make, but is not much more code.

Thanks Tatu :)

Comment: That's Jackson's author, the best reference you can have. By the way, where did you get the answer?   :)

Comment: How did you build the TokenBuffer? It takes different arguments and I am unsure of what to use in a general purpose cloning function.

Comment: @Tarmo it's a good question. I couldn't find the answer. (I didn't use the code, we ended up with different approach.)

Comment: I just had a quick go with this, and it seems it's actually slightly faster than `Kryo.copy` (In my usecase anyway. And well, it doesn't do the same thing. Still.). I'm baffled.

Comment: The TokenBuffer can be created with ```TokenBuffer tb = new TokenBuffer(objectMapper, false);```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied my "valueNode" during iteration and made a copy of it using ObjectMapper now "copyJsonNode" is the replica of "valueNode" which i need for further implementation.

```
  if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {

                JsonNode valueNode = entry.getValue();
                
                String copyjson = valueNode.toString();

                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

                JsonNode copyJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(copyjson);

               ....}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to be far slower than just doing JsonNode copyJsonNode = valueNode.deepCopy() ?? Seems like parsing a string to JSON would take longer than copying an object that's already parsed.

Comment: @bobo: All your edits are bad, please stop making them until you read up in meta.stackoverflow.com about making correct edit choices.